# Plotting a line without negative values

Tags: trigonometry

Is it possible to have a line a equation of sine without negative values. Not the same as sin(abs(x)) as negative values would be reflected in the x-axis. I'm looking for an equation where negative values of sin are converted to 0, looking not too dissimilar to a toblerone.

Comment: You could use $(|\sin(x)|+\sin(x))/2,$ if you're okay with using an absolute value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about $f(x)=\max(\sin(x),0)$?

[image: max(sin(x),0)]

**Edit:** The function given by @RideTheWavelet in his comment is precisely this one, stated in different form.

Comment: Thanks, that is exactly what I wanted. Also credit to @RideTheWavelet.